# VBA equivalent of Autosum

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Is there a VBA equivalent of Alt+= (Autosum) to sum a continuous block of numbers?

I have tried a using SendKeys "%=" but this only gives SUM() without the reference.

Edit: I have rows of data followed by 2 blank rows, beneath each set of data I want to add a sum.

```
Amount Description  
500 Text1  
500 Text2  
SUM HERE OF AMOUNT  

600 Text1  
600 Text2  
600 text3  
SUM HERE OF AMOUNT
```

Comment: did you try recording a macro and looking at the results?

Comment: What do you want to autosum? Selection? Range above selection? Why do you need to do it in VBA?

Comment: No such equivalent as standard function/procedure. You must create your own procedure, where you must check if CurrentCell.Offset(-1,0) is empty (i.e. does you must to sum horizontal or vertical range).

Answer (score 2):

*You may use these VBA Macro as Standard Module:*

```
Sub AutoSumRange()
 Dim lCell As Range
 Set lCell = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) 

 With Sheet1
 lCell.Formula = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)))
 End With
End Sub
```

**N.B.**

- This Macro will put `SUM` in the Last Row/Cell in Column `A`(*suppose
  you have value in `A2:A5`, then in `A6` and so on*) and adjust every
  new value as and when inserted.
- Cell A1 has Header value.

---

**Edited:**

*Adding this VBA code since reader's observation suggests to apply the `SUM` Formula in Last Cell & Macro should work like Keyboard Shortcut.*

[image]

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Set Rng = Range("N1:N" & Range("N1").End(xlDown).Row)
    Set c = Range("N1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    c.Formula = "=SUM(" & Rng.Address(False, False) & ")"
End Sub
```

---

**N.B.**

- Create Keyboard Shortcut to **R**UN the Macro.

[image]

- In above codes, Sheet Name & Cell references are editable.

Comment: "This Macro will put SUM in the Last Row/Cell in Column A(suppose you have value in A2:A5, then in A6 and so on) and adjust every new value as and when inserted." - that's not true worksheetfunction returns the sum as amount, not inserting formula into cell, it won't update automatically. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.sum

Comment: @MátéJuhász, I don't  think that OP is in need of Auto  updation,,, but   this works successfully when new value inserted (insert row) or modified & RUN it,,, !

Comment: @MátéJuhász,, I've updated the post ,, new Macro inserts formula as well RUN through KB Shortcut also.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Sub which works with your test data:

```
Sub AutoSumColumn()
    Dim rngToSum As Range
    Dim TopCell As Range
    Dim BottomCell As Range

    Set rngToSum = Intersect(Selection.EntireColumn, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    Set TopCell = rngToSum.Cells(1, 1)
    If TopCell.Value = vbNullString Then
        Set TopCell = TopCell.End(xlDown)
    End If
    Do
        Set BottomCell = TopCell.End(xlDown)
        BottomCell.Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=sum(" & Range(TopCell, BottomCell).Address & ")"
        Set TopCell = BottomCell.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown)
    Loop Until Intersect(rngToSum, TopCell) Is Nothing
End Sub
```

How it works:

- select any cell in the column where you want to add autosum
- start the macro

The macro then creates sum formula for each continuous range. It'll include reference to text fields too, however it won't affect result.

Sheet after running the macro:

[image]

Comment: ,, if I'm not wrong OP has never demanded for SUBTOTALs,,, but the concern was how to update Column Total,,, !!

Comment: Also,, whenever the location changes it doesn't works suppose I've data from `A15:A18` and I've selected Cell `A19` ,, this macro puts formula `=SUM(A1:A18)`,, which should `=SUM(A15:A18)` !

Comment: @RajeshS This code works on the sample data provided by OP.

Comment: @ Máté Juhász ,, when I've had posted my answer Yday,, Op hasn't any Sample data,, !! And no link is available with post also.

Comment: @MátéJuhász This almost works but for one lines (3rd example) it breaks down it keeps going to the next lot and then sums both.